# How to split a String into 3 STRINGS

Tags: java, string

Can someone please tell me how to split this string?

Sample Input

```
String in = "Erin M Haggens";
```

Desired Output

```
String str1 = "Erin";
String str2 = "M";
String str3 = "Haggens";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method.

The code `myStr.split("\\s+")` should work for you. Then you can use each element of the returned array as one of your outputted strings.